# Rational points and resolution of singularities

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is an algebraic variety over a field $F$ of characteristic 0. By resolution of singularities, there is a nonsingular variety $Y$ over $F$ with a proper birational morphism $Y \rightarrow X$.

It is true that a rational point on $Y$ induces one on $X$. How about the converse? Are there examples where $X$ admits a rational point but $Y$ doesn't?

Comment: If $\sigma:Y\to X$ is the resolution morphism then for every element $p:Spec(F)\to Y$ of $Y(F)$ we have $\sigma\circ p:Spec (F)\to X$ an element of $X(F)$.

Comment: But what if $p$ lands inside the part of $Y$ where $\sigma$ is not defined?

Comment: The desingularization morphism is (can be constructed as) a morphism, it is defined in all of $Y$. The inverse $X\to Y$ is the one that is not. Recall that Hironaka constructed it as a composition of blowups. From $Y$ to $X$ these are just polynomial maps.

Comment: I see, thanks. I have updated my question accordingly.